# Disabling password prompt while running sftp command from Unix Script

Tags: shell, unix, passwords, sftp

I can run sftp script from Unix shell script.

But it prompts for connecting servers password.

How do I configure password in sftp command from the unix shell script sothat the file can be transfered without human intervention.

My script is as below.

```
/usr/bin/sftp ${USER}@${HOST} <<EOF
cd  ${PATH}
mput *.csv
quit
EOF
```

Comment: [How to auto type password for SCP or SFTP to automate it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26480/how-to-auto-type-password-for-scp-or-sftp-to-automate-it), hope this will do you a help

Comment: Thanks..But above link didnt really serve my purpose. Neither "spawn" nor "expect" worked. Is not there any other way to provide the password through script? ftp provides options for non interactive authentication. There must be a way out with sftp too. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

you must generate id_rsa in unix.
script for generate id_rsa :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

or visit this link : http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/linux-unix-bsd/create-rsa-dsa-keys-ssh/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using sftp command, you should use **lftp** command. With this command you can give your password with option -u and run remote commands with options -e, with only one command line, so very easily inside a script.